# Testing during android development

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, intellij-idea, android-testing

I am wondering what is the fastest way of making quick simple unit tests for methods in InteliJ idea during android development. Do we need to test it via device? Is it not faster to do this tests in other tool without this slow android-device(or emulator) usage? Any up to date resources would be usefull.

Answer (score 0):

There is an approach to make 'logic library' as a jar. Then you can test it using simple JUnits.
I don't know the better way for Graphics, layouts, etc than using real devices and emulators for screens you don't have access to.

Comment: And how about code logic tests (eg. test output for simple method). No UI/grapchis etc.